# how to set default values for all new users in firebase using android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

How to set a default integer(0) value for all the new user who signup for the first time using google sign in, but for old users(who signed up earlier) the value should not change on clearing app data of the app.

For example, I am new user who signed up for the first time I got 30 points in score, and in the app, I play some task to earn more and now I got 60 points, but when I delete app data again I am getting 30 points on sign in

Please see the code

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    //getting the auth credential
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    //Now using firebase we are signing in the user here
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                        DatabaseReference UserId = databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        if (user.getUid() != null){
                            UserId.getDatabase();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                            main2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(main2);
                        }else {
                            UserId.child("Score").setValue(30);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                            main2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(main2);
                        }


                    } else {
                        // If the sign in fails displays a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                }
            });
}
```

**When I replace this code**

```
if (user.getUid() != null){
                        UserId.getDatabase();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                        main2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(main2);
                    }else {
                        UserId.child("Score").setValue(30);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                        main2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(main2);
                    }
```

**To**

```
         UserId.child("Score").setValue(30);

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                            main2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(main2);
```

**New uid with score is created in my firebase database but the problem is when I clear app data and again sign in score become 30, but if I dont replace the code new user is not created in database but they are authenticated with score null**

So please tell me how I can make this work?

I am using their uid to track
Thanks, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is there any place in your code in which you revoke user access?

Comment: no I did not write revoke users access

Comment: please see the updated question, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Now I made it work by myself by creating two functions to check if user is new or not then added simultaneously using uid through valueaddedeventlistener**

**Here is the code for sign in**

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    //getting the auth credential
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    //Now using firebase we are signing in the user here
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        final DatabaseReference UserId = databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        final String uid = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
                        databaseReference.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                                new ValueEventListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                        //String uid1 = dataSnapshot.hasChild(uid);

                                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(uid)) {
                                            //Old User
                                            userAlreadyExistsScore();

                                        } else {
                                            // User Not Yet Exists
                                            newUserScore();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

                                    }
                                }

                        );

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

**Here is code for new user**

```
private void newUserScore(){
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    final DatabaseReference UserId = databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    UserId.child("Score").setValue(30);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
    main2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(main2);

}
```

**Here is code for user already exists**

```
private void userAlreadyExistsScore(){

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    final DatabaseReference UserId = databaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());


    if (user != null){

        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Integer Score = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                UserId.child("Score").setValue(Score);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        UserId.child("Score").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent main2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
        main2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(main2);

    }
}
```